# How to implement a loop wherein: Numbers cannot be used in the middle of the input; they must come at the end?

Tags: python, loops

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):

# All vanity plates must start with at least two letters
    if s[0].isalpha() == False or s[1].isalpha() == False:
        return False

# vanity plates may contain a maximum of 6 characters (letters or numbers) and a minimum of 2 characters
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False

# Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end

# TODO



# No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed
    for c in s:
        if c in [".", " ", ",", "!", "?"]:
            return False

# PASSES ALL TESTS
    return True


main()
```

Here's my project on Vanity Plates request... there are certain criteria for the input, all of which except one has been successfully implemented. Kindly help me out with the one stating "**Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end**".

Comment: Can you add an example with expected output?

Comment: @KaviHarjani For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.

Comment: Would `AA` be valid?

Comment: @khelwood yes, it would as it contains 2 characters and one of the criteria states that the 'vanity plate name' must be at least 2 characters long and can have a maximum of 6 characters!

Comment: So the thing you need to check is whether there is any number that is followed by a letter.

Comment: @khelwood yea I suppose... but how do I do that? Sorry, but I'm a newbie to this as I've just taken an introductory course till date. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you allowed to use [regular expressions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: @khelwood no, sorry... this assignment is strictly limited to loops such as for, while, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you might do it:

```py
def is_valid(s):
    if not (2 <= len(s) <= 6):
        return False
    if not s[:2].isalpha():
        # If the first two characters are not letters, it is invalid
        return False
    any_numbers = False
    for c in s:
        if c.isdigit():
            if c=='0' and not any_numbers:
               # 0 cannot be the first digit
               return False
            any_numbers = True
        elif c.isalpha():
            if any_numbers:
                # If a letter comes after a number, it is invalid
                return False
        else:
            # If the character is not a letter or number, it is invalid
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if the first and second number is digit, if yes then false
next check if length is minimum 2 and maximum 6 else false
third check if starting from first number, end is number else False

```
number = "A2AA222"


def is_valid(number):
    if not 2 <= len(number) <= 6:
        return False
    elif number[0].isdigit() or number[1].isdigit():
        return False
    elif not number[:2].isalpha():
        return False    

    first_number = [num for num in number if num.isdigit()][0]
    first_number = number.index(first_number)
    number_list = number[first_number:]

    if number_list.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

is_valid(number)
```